# How to count all words in a sentence excluding all forms of white space with regex and Julia

Tags: regex, julia

I am trying to match all the words in the sentence:

```
"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled.
```

I tried:

```
([A-Za-z\d(^\n$)]+('[A-Za-z]+)?)
```

but I don't want to match `\nSo` as a word. Only `So`. As a matter of fact, I want to exclude all forms of white space like `\n` or `\t`.

My `Julia` code is:

```
sentence = """"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled."""
regex = r"([A-Za-z\d(^\n$)]+('[A-Za-z]+)?)"
v =[m.match for m = eachmatch(regex, sentence)]
```

Comment: Ok, it uses PCRE. You may use `\\[rnt](*SKIP)(*F)|\w+(?:['-]\w+)*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/D52SCV/3))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237125/discussion-between-sbac-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the `\r`, `\n` and `\t` are two-letter combinations in your texts.

Since Julia uses PCRE you can use a SKIP-FAIL regex here to easily ingore these combinations from matches:

```php
\\[rnt](*SKIP)(*F)|\w+(?:['-]\w+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RYu9tn/1). *Details*:

- `\\[rnt](*SKIP)(*F)` - a `\` char and then either `r`, `n` or `t`, and then the matched chars are dropped, the match is failed and the engine starts looking for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\w+(?:['-]\w+)*` - one or more word chars and then zero or more repetitions of `'` or `-` and then one or more chars.

In Julia:

```
julia> sentence = """"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled."""
"\"That's the password: 'PASSWORD 123'!\", cried the Special Agent.\nSo I fled."

julia> regex = r"\\[rnt](*SKIP)(*F)|\w+(?:['-]\w+)*"
r"\\[rnt](*SKIP)(*F)|\w+(?:['-]\w+)*"

julia> v =[m.match for m = eachmatch(regex, sentence)]
12-element Vector{SubString{String}}:
"That's"
"the"
"password"
"PASSWORD"
"123"
"cried"
"the"
"Special"
"Agent"
"So"
"I"
"fled"
```

See the [online Julia demo](https://tio.run/##TY1Ba4MwGIbv/opv9mBiO2ErvQilFEqh9LDSDHYwgiH5qhaNkmS6Q/@7C8JGby/P@/K89@@mFptpsqgdaomwhSL8rISLLLgKoRfWjp1RKUSXPWNfH9cDvL2vo5dwBdLUqOYV61HWooF96TUJ55p1cIJbgyopgie1dabWJfkjNDBY4o8vTMh5ZrTLSczOpwsl8ZE@@LgkuzSLXnOfaBzCAg5KqWCAbdYmrXCygltnoPUCFLKaCZmVK/j/yIPenzoy0Gn6BQ).